# what's the best way to create array combinations with static and dynamic values

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, combinatorics, code-readability

After long attempts, I managed to write a script that creates all the combinations of the array and you can set the levels of combinations.

But how to make an option with restrictions of combinations, when some elements remain in position (static) and others around them change (dynamic).

That's what I need:output sample:

```
  min
  "static1", "static2", "static3" // (limited by number of static item if min 3) 
  "static2", "static1", "static3" // if true allow change order of main
  (4) min+1
  ["others1", "static1", "static2", "static3"]
  ["static1", "others1", "static2", "static3"]
  ["others1", "static2", "static1", "static3"]
  ...
  ["others1", "static2", "static1", "static3"]  true // iIf true, then you can allow static values to reorder
  ["others1", "static2", "static1", "static3"]  true
  ...
  (7) min+4
  ["other", "static1", "other1", "static2", "other1", "static3", "other1"] 
  ...
  (9) max+6 
  ["other2", "static1", "other1", "static2", "other2", "other1", "static3", "other3", "other1"]
  ...
```

I realized that most likely I'm doing everything wrong. Perhaps there is a better way to do this.
My algorithm has a poor speed, often a message about insufficient memory, too many cycles, bad readability ...
Therefore, I ask you to show me how best to make such combinations.

```js
     var static_arr1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
     var static_arr2 = ['a','b','c','d'];
     var combin_arr1 = ['a','b','c','d'];var p= [];var max ="6";
     var a = [static_arr1, static_arr2, combin_arr1]; // OR var a = ['static_arr1':static_arr1,'static_arr2':static_arr2,'combin_arr1':combin_arr1]; if you prefer use multidimension array no problems, convert arrays to array of arrays or function create(){var nam = arguments.name;  return {val: arguments,}}
     
      // ------------------------------------  Count arrays:
     for (var key in window) {var ss = key;
          if( ss.indexOf("tic_") > -1){p.push(key);var min = p.length;  console.log(min);}}   // count global static arrays and set min level of combinations
     
     // =====================================

     function get1DArray(arr){return arr.join().split(",");}                                    // if array multidimensional simple convert to 1d  - lost information and position:( +fast,siple , сheck: if(this.filter(Array.isArray).length > 1){}
     
     Array.prototype.combine=function combine(k){    var toCombine=get1DArray(this);   var last; 
      // ------------------------------------
         function combi(n,comb){var combs=[];
     
             for ( var x=0,y=comb.length;x<y;x++){var v = comb[x];    for ( var l=0,m=toCombine.length;l<m;l++){   
     
                     combs.push(comb[x]+toCombine[l]); 
                 }
             }
     
     
     // recursion
             if (n<k-1){n++;combi(n,combs);}
                                             else{last=combs;}        }
      // ------------------------------------END func
     
         combi(1,toCombine);
         return last;
     }
     
     // ===================================== Example:
     
     for (var i = min; i <= max;i++) { console.log(i)  // get levels from min and max
     var toCombine=[combin_arr1, static_arr2, static_arr1];   
     var results=toCombine.combine(i);
     console.log(results)
      }
```

Comment: In your `min+4` and `min+6` examples, why are there duplicates?

Comment: This is my reserve for the future.
I wanted to create an algorithm in the future that would work with duplicates as well.Now we can ignore duplicates.